# How can i implicity declare function template's argument if one of the arguments is another function

Tags: c++, function, templates

i have a template function that looks like this:

```
template<class F, class... Args>
auto ThreadPool::enqueue(F&& f, Args&&... args)
-> std::future<typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type>
```

and im trying to call it like so

```
pool.enqueue<void,TCPServer,ReceivedSocketData,std::unordered_map,std::mutex>(serverThreadFunction, &server, receivedData,topicsData,&allDataLock);
```

however it gives me the error C++

```
no instance of function template matches the argument list  
argument types are: (void (TCPServer *server, ReceivedSocketData &&data,
 std::unordered_map<std::string, topic, std::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string>,
 std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, topic>>> &map, 
std::mutex *lock), TCPServer *, ReceivedSocketData, std::unordered_map<std::string, topic, std::hash<std::string>, 
std::equal_to<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<const 
std::string, topic>>>, std::mutex *)            object type is: ThreadPool
```

i assume the issue is I dont know how to explicitly declare types for the arguments who's type can't be assessed. Aside from that i'm not sure why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call it as

```
pool.enqueue(serverThreadFunction, &server, receivedData, topicsData, &allDataLock);
```

Template arguments can be deduced from function argument/parameter pairs. In particular if the function template uses a template parameter as a forwarding reference (e.g. `F` in `F&&` or `Args` in `Args&&`), then not specifying the corresponding template argument and letting it be deduced is the only sensible and expected use.

Template arguments should usually only be specified explicitly for template parameters that *aren't* used in a type of a function parameter.

---

Additionally, based purely on the types mentioned in the error message, `serverThreadFunction` has a rvalue reference to `ReceivedSocketData` parameter and so won't accept a lvalue argument (such as `receivedData`) for it. Pass it a rvalue instead.

Comment: if i write that then the following error is given ---C++ no instance of function template matches the argument list            argument types are: (void (TCPServer *server, ReceivedSocketData &&data, std::unordered_map<std::string, topic, std::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, topic>>> &map, std::mutex *lock), TCPServer *, ReceivedSocketData, std::unordered_map<std::string, topic, std::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, topic>>>, std::mutex *)            object type is: ThreadPool

Comment: @Ted According to the types you are listing `serverThreadFunction` wants a `ReceivedSocketData` rvalue, but you are giving it a lvalue (`receivedData`).